# RTSP server SET_PARAMETER request response

Tags: c, rtsp

```
C->S: SET_PARAMETER rtsp://example.com/fizzle/foo RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 421
Content-length: 20
Content-type: text/parameters
barparam: barstuff

S->C: RTSP/1.0 451 Invalid Parameter
CSeq: 421
Content-length: 10
Content-type: text/parameters
barparam
```

I am programming a RTSP server, if client want to set volume parameter in `SET_PARAMETER`, but server doesn't really set the volume as the message send, just respond the response message. Then can the connection be closed?

Comment: Why would you want to drop connection on server rather than responding with error response keeping connection alive?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I apologize my poor explanation. Actually I don't want to close the connection. I'm writing the code, but after response the set_parameter request correctly, the client send me a teardown request. I don't know the reason. So I guess if I don't really set the parameter as the request, if the connection can close?

Comment: I see now - your server side behavior looks good then. It's hard to tell what client did not like but you are doing it right from the server side. It's up to client to move on or close the connection. If you would like to mimic another server, you perhaps would want to check communication to another RTSP server where this client likes the response and moves on further.